# SQL compilation error invalid identifier 'COLUMN_NAME' when using df.to_sql()

Tags: python, sql, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm working on some code to push a dataframe to snowflake using the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import pd_writer
from sqlalchemy.types import String
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(URL(
    user='service account',
    password='password',
    account='account',
    database='database',
    schema='schema',
    warehouse='warehouse',
    role="role"
    ))
df.columns = map(lambda x: str(x).upper(), df.columns)

df.to_sql(name=table_name.lower(), con=engine, schema="schema", index=False, if_exists='append', method=pd_writer, dtype={'field': String})

engine.dispose()
```

However, I am promped with the error:

```
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 000904 (42000): SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 3,361
invalid identifier 'COLUMN_NAME_1234'
```

The column is of string type, any suggestions?

The df is 100s of columns, each value contained being string type

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `df.to_sql()` is trying to write to a table and it expects that table to have a column called 'COLUMN_NAME_1234'. But it doesn't have that column, hence the error.

Try `if_exists= replace` , which will replace the existing table with one that has that column - if starting a new table would be the solution to your problem.